# How to add an option column in MySQL (Xampp 8.0.0)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to modify the table users adding the column crypto

Trying to execute this query but I'm getting an error:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `crypto` VARCHAR(255) NULL '{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin": 0, "binance-coin": 0, "monero": 0, "dash": 0, "zcash": 0, "maker": 0}';
```

This is the error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax**

[image]

If I try to create the column manually and setting the default values I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a column DEFAULT value with the `DEFAULT` keyword.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `crypto` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin": 0, "binance-coin": 0, "monero": 0, "dash": 0, "zcash": 0, "maker": 0}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forget `DEFAULT` in your query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `crypto` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT '{"bitcoin": 0, "ethereum": 0, "bitcoin-cash": 0, "bitcoin-sv": 0, "litecoin": 0, "binance-coin": 0, "monero": 0, "dash": 0, "zcash": 0, "maker": 0}';
```